# Excel - Change font color of a row on double click

Tags: microsoft-excel, colors, vbscript

I'm trying to change the font color of the row in which the cell is located when I double click it from black to grey, and the opposite when it's already grey. Here is the code I'm trying:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Excel.Range, Cancel As Boolean)
   If Target.FormatConditions.Item.Font.ColorIndex <> 0 Then
     Cell.EntireRow.FormatConditions.Item.Font.ColorIndex = 0
   Else
     Target.FormatConditions.Item.Font.ColorIndex = 8
   End If
   Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @jacob jan tuinstra: how to mark the text as code? I remember it involves ctr+ something

Comment: In the edit mode of the question, select the code and press the curly brackets. You can also use this <code></code>. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you are trying to set a conditional format. You can work directly on the font color. With black = color index 1 and grey = color index 16:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Excel.Range, Cancel As Boolean)
     If Target.Font.ColorIndex <> 1 Then
         'not black? -> set to black
         Target.EntireRow.Font.ColorIndex = 1
     Else
         'black? -> set to grey
         Target.EntireRow.Font.ColorIndex = 16
     End If
     Cancel = True
End Sub
```

This code applies only to the specific worksheet into which you have entered the code in the VBA editor.

To have the action automatically apply to every sheet in the workbook, you need to change the event reference in the procedure declaration to `Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)`.

The revised code must be entered into the editor's code pane for `ThisWorkbook`. (It is not necessary to modify the body of the code.)

If you want to limit the action - and its results - to specific columns or rows, only a modest change in approach is required:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
'   only double-clicks in columns B and C will trigger action
    If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("B:C")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Font.ColorIndex <> 1 Then
'           only fonts in columns B and C will be modified
            Sh.Range("B:C").Font.ColorIndex = 1
        Else
            Sh.Range("B:C").Font.ColorIndex = 16
        End If
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I was not familiar with that object tree, so I guess I've choosen the wrong one. You fixed it. thanks

Comment: let me ask this, how to make that code work for the whole workbook?

Comment: Instead of Target.EntireRow.Font..., use Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Font....

Comment: chuff Sorry, I did not express myself correctly, I mean to not have to copy that code to every sheet. I would like to put the code somehow that it would work for the entire workbook (not talking about change the color of the whole workbook).

Comment: See my amended answer, Fernando.

Comment: wonderfull! thanks again! One last question, if I want to change text color of just the columns B and C how to would you do it?

Comment: only problem is that it's changing all the cells in those 2 columns (B and C) but I would like to alter only the target cells in those columns (ie, if I double click cell B3 then only B3 and B2 would change.

Comment: Change `Sh.Range("B:C").Font.ColorIndex` to `Sh.Range("B" & Target.Row & ":C" & Target.Row).Font.ColorIndex = 1`.